# Parallax (relative) layer groups overlay eachother

Tags: css

I don't get why this is happening:
I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/d5jehq02/1

```
<div class="para_group"> 
   <div class="para_layer para_layer_back"> 
     <h2>background</h2>  
   </div> 
   <div class="para_layer para_layer_front"> 
     <h2>forefront</h2> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

I am trying to create a parallax scrolling effect and although the 2 parent layers (class='para_group') have position='relative', still onr of the child divs - specifically   seems to overlap its parent layer...

If you see the example link above, you will realize that the background layer from the 2nd group - seems to overlap the first group all together - when it shouldn't - the group's position is set to relative - therefore block objects (the parent divs) should appear one below the other...
I cannot get my mind around this one :(

Comment: I'm not sure I really get what is the question here.

Comment: I dont understand why children from group 2 (para_group) (second para_group > para_layer_back) overlap group 1 (para_group) - since both groups have position:relative

Comment: Have you tried adding z-index:2 and z-index:1 on the first and second groups respectively?

Answer (score 0):

The relativity of the conventional html positioning in here is seriously disturbed by the fact that the layer_back elements AND layer_front elements are actually moved into 3d context and scaled.

To achieve the parallax effect, what is done in here is:

Setting 1px perspective (camera set 1px away from the rendering plane).

```
.parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
}
```

Moving the background layers 1px deeper into the field of view while at the same time scaling them to be twice as large.

```
.para_layer_back {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
```

^ This is the heart of the parallax effect, as moving the elements 1px deeper when we have perspective set at 1px, positions the elements twice as far from the camera as the front layers which are translateZ'd by 0. This produces the parallax effect while scrolling, but also makes the elements appear smaller, because they're further away (the perspective effect).

That's why they are scale(2)'d so they appear in their original size.

Thing is, they're moved away from the camera without changing their relative positions (they're right next to each other then), and then **they're scaled in-place**, the scale operation having transform-origin set at their centers, **makes them get larger and overlap each other**.

What you could do to solve the problem is to work on first moving them away from each other before scaling them.

Take a look at the forked and updated fiddle where I've removed the "scale(2)" part on the back layers, they are in the back, and they are positioned properly (without overlapping).
http://jsfiddle.net/3x150vsx/1/

```
.para_layer_back {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1);
}
```

The solution to your problem lies in moving them away from each other before you try to scale them up.

Good luck :>

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I understand the 'logistics' behind parallax scrolling - however my comments are the following:
- its not the relationship between the children divs (front + back) that puzzles me. Its the relationship between the 2 parent divs (para-group) that does so.
- making them larger (scale:2) is - according to this site: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites - not making them larger - but reverting them back to their original size. So that does not explain the overlapping.

Comment: also I see your point, but the example provided does not present any parallax scrolling though...?

Comment: You're not scaling the parent  .para-group divs. You're scaling the .para_layer_back background divs (children of para-group). And the back divs are overlapping, not the parent divs grouping them.

Comment: Looks like the 2nd background layer (from the second group) is overlapping the first background layer (from the first group) so in a sense - yes - the groups are overlapping each other since their children so do.